# Create an array in bash and choose one element out of it

Tags: bash

I found this

```
channel_map = {
    "2412" : 1,
    "2417" : 2,
    "2422" : 3,
    "2427" : 4,
    "2432" : 5,
    "2437" : 6,
    "2442" : 7,
    "2447" : 8,
    "2452" : 9,
    "2457" : 10,
    "2462" : 11,
    "2467" : 12,
    "2472" : 13,
    "2484" : 14
}
```

how do i convert this, so I can use this in a bash script?

I would like to define

$CHANNEL=11

and the script should use the right frequency.

the command I use is for example:

```
iw dev wlan0 ibss join $ESSID 2412 HT40+ fixed-freq $CELLID
```

Comment: What is the underlying use case here?  Every linux command I can find will take the channel number directly, and so use the correct frequency without you needing to convert.  What does your script do?

Comment: I edited the title to clarify my subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the answer rubo77 is looking for is:

```
#!/bin/sh –
channel_map[1]=2412
channel_map[2]=2417
channel_map[3]=2422
channel_map[4]=2427
channel_map[5]=2432
channel_map[6]=2437
channel_map[7]=2442
channel_map[8]=2447
channel_map[9]=2452
channel_map[10]=2457
channel_map[11]=2462
channel_map[12]=2467
channel_map[13]=2472
channel_map[14]=2484

channel=11
echo ${channel_map[$channel]}
```

A more compact way of doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
channel_map=(XYZZY 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 \
                   2462 2467 2472 2484)

channel=11
echo ${channel_map[$channel]}
```

channel_map is an array. The `XYZZY` is a placeholder; it will be assigned to `channel_map[0]`.

Comment: this doesen't work anymore

Comment: I edited the compact way, now it works

Answer (score 1):

if you're just looking to pull the corresponding number from that file, try:

```
awk -v chan=$CHANNEL '{if($3 ~ chan","){gsub("\"","",$1);print $1}}' map
```

where `map` is your input file, and `$CHANNEL` is set to the channel you're looking up.

Comment: this works for a file too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your full implementation, but as a quick way to get it accomplished.. Though as @Paul said - most I know of take the channel number rather than Frequency:

```
#!/bin/bash

channel=${1:-"6"}   # Channel will equal the command line argument, default to "6" if empty.
let channel-=1      # This lets you specify 1 - 14 instead of the 0-13 base of an array

freq=(2412 2417 2422 nnnn)  # The channel values, 1-14

echo ${freq[${channel}]}
```

Be sure to save it as whatever.sh and `chmod +x whatever.sh`.  Then you can just type `./whatever.sh 4` (from the same directory) and the above will echo `2427`